# How can I make search engines find the blog in my website?

Tags: seo, search-engine, blogger

I'm trying to improve the SEO of a website. I'm using the tool WooRank to improve some aspects of this web, and I created a blog with Blogger. I have put an image in my homepage with a link to my blog in Blogger, but WooRank keeps warning me that I don't have a blog. My blog has links to my website in my profile, and in the entries. Some SEO tools can find my blog from a landing page, linking to the blogspot URL from an image in the header and in the footer, but some not. Any ideas on how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a text link using the anchor text 'blog', or if you haven't already, include the word 'blog' in the alt attribute on the image that you link out to the blog.

Sam

Answer (score 0):

Try submitting the link to [The Google URL submitter](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url?pli=1) for a highlight at indexing. Also, make sure your robots.txt is not blocking the webpage or the folder from being indexed. If your website does not have a robots file, add a blank one.

Focus on Google, once they index the page, the other engines will follow.